# How can I upload a file to the Sitecore media library in code using an ASP FileUpload control?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

Here is what I have tried and it doesn't seem to work.  I don't get any errors, but it doesn't seem to add the file to the media library either.

```cs
using(new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
  if(myFileControl.HasFile)
  {
    MediaCreatorOptions _options = new MediaCreatorOptions();
    _options.Database = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    _options.FileBased = false;
    _options.IncludeExtensionInItemName = false;
    _options.KeepExisting = false;
    _options.Versioned = false;
    _options.Destination = "/sitecore/media library";
    MediaItem _newFile = MediaManager.Creator.CreateFromStream(myFileControl.FileContent, myFileControl.FileName, _options);
  }
}
```

My biggest issue is that I don't really understand what some of the different parameters and properties do.  What is the "Destination" property for the MediaCreatorOptions?  Is it supposed to be just a folder?  Is it supposed to have the item name also?  What are the three parameters for the CreateFromStream method?  The first one seems to be the Stream - I get that.  But the second was says "FileName".  What is this supposed to be?  If I am creating from a Stream why do I need to tell Sitecore the FileName?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your problem here is that you're not using the proper options for the Sitecore API call. You don't have a real destination.. which is where you would specify the Sitecore item that will become your item... not just a folder. It looks like you're trying to create the media library item.

Per the Content API Book on SDN:

How to Create Media Items Using APIs

You can use the Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator and 
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions classes to create media items from files. 
For example, to create the media item /Sitecore/Media Library/Images/Sample in the 
Master database from the file C:\temp\sample.jpg:

```cs
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions options =  new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions();
options.Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
options.Language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.DefaultLanguage);
options.Versioned = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault;
options.Destination = "/sitecore/media library/images/Sample";
options.FileBased = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Media.UploadAsFiles;
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem sample = creator.CreateFromFile(@"C:\temp\sample.jpg",options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Corey, I'm not sure if this is still relevant, but I just ran into the exact same questions you did.  @divamatrix did not really answer the stream questions and I would like to fill out this question in case someone else (or myself again) need the answers.

> What is the "Destination" property for the MediaCreatorOptions?

As @divamatrix pointed out, the `Destination` property in `MediaCreatorOptions` is where you would like your MediaItem to live in the Sitecore Media Library (ex. /sitecore/Media Library/Images/Created Image)

> Is it supposed to be just a folder? Is it supposed to have the item name also?

No, it should not be the name of a folder currently in the media library. It should be the path of the item you would like created including the name of the item you would like created (see above).

> What are the three parameters for the CreateFromStream method? The first one seems to be the Stream - I get that. But the second was says "FileName". What is this supposed to be? If I am creating from a Stream why do I need to tell Sitecore the FileName?

The filename is ignored if you set the `Destination` with the `MediaCreatorOptions` because the `GetItemPath` method will just return `options.Destination` if not null or empty. If you do not set `Destination`, the `GetItemPath` method will try it's best to give you a proper path in the media library.  In essence, when using CreateFromStream (as far as I can tell), set the `Destination` in `MediaCreatorOptions`, or set the `filePath` to where you would like your item to be and the `GetItemPath` method will try to put it there, but may throw exceptions if it is unable to.